Why is the img-fluid class not working on my first cloud image?
I'm trying to make two cloud images responsive on my webpage, but the first cloud image isn't scaling properly like the second one. I am using Bootstrap's img-fluid class to achieve responsiveness.


.first-cloud-image {
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 70%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Ensure the image doesn't exceed its container width */
}

.text-center>div>p {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #11999e;
}

.text-center>h1 {
  font-family: Sacramento;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 90px;
  color: #11999e !important;
}

body>div {
  background-color: #e4f9f5;
  margin: 0;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>About Me</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <!-- adding the first cloud image with img-fluid class -->
    <img src="./images/cloud.png" alt="image of a cloud" class="img-fluid first-cloud-image">
    <!-- This is the hero -->
    <div class="px-4 my-5 text-center">
      <h1 class="display-4 fw-bold text-body-emphasis">I'm Vishwas.</h1>
      <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
        <p class="lead mb-4">a programmer.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="overflow-hidden" style="max-height: 60vh;">
        <div class="image-container">
          <!-- adding the second cloud image -->
          <div>
            <img src="images/cloud.png" alt="image of a cloud" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <!-- adding the image of the mountain -->
          <div>
            <img src="./images/mountain.png" class="img-fluid" alt="image of a mountain" width="700" loading="lazy">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



The img-fluid class is working fine for the second cloud image and the mountain image, making them responsive. However, the first cloud image is not scaling dynamically with the screen size.
What I've Tried:

I applied the img-fluid class to the first cloud image, but it still does not respond to screen          size changes like the other images.
I ensured that max-width: 100% and height: auto are set for .first-cloud-image in the CSS.


We seem to be missing some CSS. What does the first-cloud class do styling-wise? We will be much more able to help if you could create a runnable snippet, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
